# How to get curve to twist with the hooked object?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a curve using a "squared" circle as a bevel object to get a square-profile tube.
The two last control points of the curve are hooked to an object.

When I rotate that object around Y and Z axes, the "tube" follows nicely:
[image]
[image]

but around X axis the "tube" **does not** follow the object's rotation completely (it does not twist around X axis):
[image]

**Is there a way to get the curve twist along all three axes together with the object it is hooked to?**

There is an option to tilt curve control point (Curve -> Control Points -> Tilt) but that has to be done manually. Maybe somehow tying that tilt to the object ...?

I am open to all sorts of solutions as long as it allows moving and rotating the hooked object and the "tube" follows it.

Here is the file I used for the example screenshots:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a driver to the Tilt of the point.

Select the desired point and add a driver to it's Tilt.

[image: Driver]

Then go to the driver editor and do ass follow:

[image: Driver]

Now when you rotate the object the curve rotate too.

[image: GIF]

Comment: Wow! For my case the driver has to be added to both of the last two control points to get the desired behavior, but that is it! Thank you!

Comment: Well, it is not 100% accurate - it does not follow the rotation completely. It can be seen in the animation above (half of the bottom wall "sinks" in the surface of the block). And it becomes exponentially larger as the rotation around Y or Z axis gets larger. It is OK for smaller angles, though.

Comment: @spacer It is because we used the x rotation only,We will have to do some math to include the rest,Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that Type does not have to be Scripting, i.e. it can be Maximum Value and it still works.

Comment: Omar, did you have time to figure out how to prevent that unwanted rotation? I am trying to figure it out but cannot understand why would rotation on Z and Y axes influence rotation on X axis ...

Comment: @spacer Sorry,I couldn't find it out,The vector (location of the spline) affect the Z and Y rotation but not X,what we did is just including X as the 3rd dimension,The problem is that we didn't put in consideration the effect of he vector on the X rotation,Thee have to be a relation that bind them together,We just can't find it,I will try to find a solution by studying the rotation transformation matrix.But i don't promise finding a solution.